# Prove: $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ st for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $n$ st $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$, f is a polynomial.

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$, then f is a polynomial.

I'm kind of lost on this one. I know that I have to use Baire's category theorem somewhere here, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can indeed be solved using the Baire Category Theorem.

A nice discussion of variants of the problem, along with an outline of a proof of your version, can be found in the answers to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) at MathOverflow.