# Can it be determined whether the given function is necessarily a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis, polynomials

Consider a function $f\in C^\infty[0,1]$ satisfying the property that for every $x\in[0,1]$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$. The question is whether $f$ must necessarily be a polynomial.

Using the fact that $[0,1]$ is a Baire space, we can find an interval $(a,b)$ and some $n$ such that $f^{(n)}\equiv 0$ on $[0,1]\cap(a,b)$. Consequently, $f|{(a,b)}$ is a polynomial. This observation suggests that $f$ is likely to be a polynomial on most intervals of its domain. In fact, a more sophisticated statement that can be shown is that there exists a topologically dense open subset consisting of a collection of indexed open intervals $\{U_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $f|{U_k}$ is a polynomial for each $k$.

However, it is unclear whether $f$ is a polynomial on its entire domain. If $f\in C^\omega$, then by the connectedness of $[0,1]$, we can extend the interval $(a,b)$ to $[0,1]$. Nonetheless, I remain uncertain as to whether $f$ is required to be a global polynomial.

Comment: Here's a MathOverflow thread about that very question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/34059

Comment: @JohnDouma You might have misread the question. Each $n$ depends on its $x$, not the other way round yet (all the difficulty lies in interchanging the order of dependence between $n$ and $x$).

Comment: @BrunoB do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @ronno Instead I'll link to this one where it's already an answer (even if said answer is, again, just the same link): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372354/1104384